# List index out of range, python arrays

Tags: python

Code:

```
data = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,6]
section = [4,7]
    
for i in range(len(section)):
    values.append(data[section[i]])
```

I am trying to add certain values from an array to another array but I am getting `"Error: List index out of range"`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: expected Output??

Comment: `data[10]` doesn't exist.

Comment: where is `values` declared?

Answer (score 1):

section[2] == 10.  There are 10 values in data, but Python list indexes are 0 based, so they only run from 0 to 9 so data[10] is an index error.

If you intended or 4, 7 and 10 to index the 4th, 7th, and 10th items in data you need to subtract one from the values like:

```
data = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,6] section = [4,7,10]

for i in range(len(section)):
    values.append(data[section[i]-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python indexes start at 0, so your `data` list has elements indexed 0 to 9. You try to access the item at index 10 which doesn't exist. That's why you get an error.
I don't know what you want to achieve exactly, but to fix the error you can either fix the indexes contained in `section`, or you add an element to `data`, or, as suggested by Curt Welch, you substract 1 to each index (if you want those to start at 1).

BTW, the Pythonic way to iterate the elements in a list is:

```
for item in section:
    values.append(data[item]-1)
```

Using an index in a for loop is the norm in C/C++ but it is usually not needed in Python, since you can iterate on items from the list directly.

Comment: Even more *"pythonic"* will be `values.extend(itemgetter(*section)(data))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do:
Right now you are iterating over the section list

```py
for i in range(3):
    values.append(data[section[i]])
```

So for the three iterations it will be:

```
i = 0
values.append(data[section[0]])
section[0] = 4
data[4] = 7
values.append(7)

i = 1
values.append(data[section[1]])
section[1] = 7
data[7] = 10
values.append(10)

i = 2
values.append(data[section[2]])
section[2] = 10
data[10] # here is the index of out range thrown as the last index of data is 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get what your trying to do but the error is caused by the following:

the loop runs 3 times because section has 3 entries.
section[i] equals 4 the first time, 7 the second time and 10 the thrid time.
in the third run, you try to access (and append) data[section[2]], which is equal to data[10] but data has only indexes from 0-9, thats where the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Python list indices start at 0 so in the list
`data = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,6]` the indices are actually, `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
The second array references index 10. There is no index 10 as 9 is the greatest index. To resolve this error:
`values.append(data[item]-1)` which subtracts 1 from the index so that index 9 correlates to 6 in the data set
Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) out for more info